# i am not able to use same webelement multiple times? selenium java check screenshot please

Tags: java, testing, automation

i am not able to use same Webelement  multiple times? selenium java check screenshot please

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhxuI.png

Comment: 1:  Post the code not the image.  2:  What error you get is not clear. Please mention the error that you are getting. 3:  `/html` gives you the whole webpage. What is the specific element you are looking for?  4. `'html` - you did not end the quotation mark 5: If possible, provide the website link so that people can investigate and help you out.

Comment: sir i am new on stackoverflow when i am trying to write code and publish it is giving unwanted error . so i have to upload image . the question is that i have created webelement for username(sendkeys),password(send keys),login(click),logout (click) ok.
when i run it first time it is working properly ,when i am using same webelement username,password for sending keys then it is not taking .
first time - username - new , pass- 123456, login , logout .
second time username-km123,pass-12345 i trying to login with same webelement but different username password.then it is not taking any input

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `WebElement` object after page is reloaded. After the login you have to reinitiate the objects.

You can create a method where elements locating is wrapped, like this:

```
public static void login(WebDriver driver, String userName, String password) {
    WebElement userNameInput = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
    userNameInput.click();
    userNameInput.sendKeys(userName);       
    WebElement passwordInput = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
    passwordInput.click();
    passwordInput.sendKeys(password);       
    WebElement loginButton = driver.findElement(By.id("login"));
    loginButton.click();
}
```

usage will be simply:

```
login(driver, "km123", "pass");
// code to verify successful login, logout if successful, reload login page if unsuccessful
login(driver, "foo", "bar");
// code to verify unsuccessful login
```

Cutting tests into those small methods make creating new test quite simple like building something from prefabricated pieces.

Few tips:

- `Login`- don't name objects with first capital . Better to name objects with some  identifier like loginButton, cookiesAcceptButton, etc.
- don't post code as image, image is for image and code formatting is for code.
- be aware of type errors like missing quotes in `usename.sendKeys("km123);`

Comment: public static void login(WebDriver driver, String userName, String password) {  //at this line it is telling to give driver another name like driver1 
//login
WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
username.click();
username.sendKeys(userName);
   
WebElement pass = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
pass.click();
pass.sendKeys(password);
 
part 2 in next comment

Comment: //part 2  
WebElement loginuser = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/form/button"));
   loginuser.click();
  }
    
  login(driver, "km619","123456");// at thiis name it is telling to create method on click it is creating private method at end of the program
}
}

Comment: @Anand Gautam can you please help?